# Swift: When To Use 'var' And 'func'

Tags: swift, var, func

I always came across with this question when creating function or variable in swift. Consider the following implementations:

**var**

```
var isOpen: Bool
{
    // expression returning either true or false
}

var subTotal: Double
{
   return quantity * price
}
```

**func**

```
func isOpen() -> Bool
{
    // expression returning either true or false
}

func subTotal() -> Double
{
   return quantity * price
}
```

What's the best practice on this?

Comment: The best practice is naturally to use functions as functions and computed properties as properties.

Comment: This is really a matter of taste, so this should probably be closed as primarily opinion-based. But my take: if the value could easily have been a member variable given a different implementation, or if the computation is simple (ideally constant-time, though `String.uppercaseString` is a counterexample), make it a var, otherwise make it a function.

Answer (score 2):

I use `var` for fairy simple implementation with **no side effect**. If the computation takes long time or it changes something, I use `func`.